# Resizing an Android Xamarin dialog after generating data

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.android

I'm looking for a way to dynamically resize a dialog window when the data inside a scroll view doesn't fill the whole screen. Specifically, I would like to maximize the content to 90% width and height, but wrap the content if the size of the data plus the rest of the views are less than 90%.

Here's what I have done so far: I show the alert, and I've attempted to recalculate the size, but when it's not at 90%, there is a white band at the bottom of the view.

Could anyone suggest a solution to this issue?

There's some code to help.
in the example I read that Window.DecorView.height could be getting the height of my tool bar but I'm not sure.

[Edit] There's no padding of height on anything and everything thats in my header is set to wrap content to the height value

```cs
alert.Show();

            

            alert.Window.DecorView.Post(() =>
            {
                
                //tried this>>int alertHeight = View.MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec(0,MeasureSpecMode.Unspecified);
                

                //this is closer to what I need
                int alertHeight = alert.Window.DecorView.Height;
                //displayWidth 90%
                int displayWidth = (int)(Resources.DisplayMetrics.WidthPixels * 0.9);
                int displayHeight = (int)(Resources.DisplayMetrics.HeightPixels * 0.9);

                //Deciding which one to use
                if (alertHeight > displayHeight)
                {
                    alert.Window.SetLayout(displayWidth, displayHeight);
                }
                else
                {
                    alert.Window.SetLayout(displayWidth, alertHeight);
                }
            });
```

in the xml part its mostly that

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent">
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">
<!--Content-->
</LinearLayout>
<ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0px"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:stretchColumns="1"
            android:background="@android:color/white"/>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

[View of the white space](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NcEXk.png)

Answer (score 1):

I believe I have found a solution to the problem. Initially, the header was not taking up 90% of the screen width because it was set to "wrap content" in the XML. This caused it to be centered on the screen and become taller due to word wrapping.

After generating child views for the scroll view, the height of each was added to the view height, which worsened the problem. To fix this, I set the header's layout parameters to 90% width by default, ensuring it is generated at 90% from the start and preventing word wrapping.

```cs
int displayWidth = (int)(Resources.DisplayMetrics.WidthPixels * 0.9);
            LinearLayout linearHeader = view.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.unikId_Header);
            linearHeader.LayoutParameters = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(displayWidth,ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
```

I also added a loop to iterate through all the child views in the scroll view to calculate the appropriate height and ensure accuracy.

```cs
alert.Window.DecorView.Post(() =>
            {
                TableLayout table = view.FindViewById<TableLayout>(Resource.Id.TableThermosUnikIds);
                LinearLayout header = view.FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.unikId_Header);

                int contentHeight = 0;
                
                for(int i = 0;i<table.ChildCount;i++)
                {
                    contentHeight += table.GetChildAt(i).MeasuredHeightAndState;
                }
                int headerHeaight = header.MeasuredHeightAndState;
                int totalHeight = contentHeight+headerHeaight;

                int displayHeight = (int)(Resources.DisplayMetrics.HeightPixels * 0.9);

                int resultHeight = Math.Min(displayHeight, totalHeight);

                alert.Window.SetLayout(displayWidth,resultHeight);
                
                
            });
```